# Extracting function which generates primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, primary-key

I use a program which saves data into sql server compact edition 4.0 database.
I'd like to work with database directly (a lot of my data i can just ctrl+c/v between tables, program itself doesn't support it), but I can't figure out how this program generates unique identifiers.

Typical table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [DOC_EMISS_FACT]
(
   [CpStatObjEmissFactId] NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   [DocId] NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   [RSG1] DECIMAL(19,12),
   [RSG2] DECIMAL(19,12)
);
ALTER TABLE [DOC_EMISS_FACT] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__DOC_EMISS_FACT__0000000000000566] PRIMARY KEY ([CpStatObjEmissFactId], [DocId]);
```

Can I create passable primary key from this (intention is to make a csv table, modify it and import back)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to generate here.  Any combination of those two fields, as long as it's unique, is a valid primary key for this table.  If there's some other logic for these keys it's not present here.

Comment: You need to create unique combinations of  [CpStatObjEmissFactId] and [DocId]. By itself - it's not a complicated task. E.g. you can use sequences or NEWID()/NEWSEQEUNTIALID() casted to `binary` or to `nvarchar`. The problem could occur if this identifiers are used somewhere else in your database.